# php-form-builder-class files not being uploaded

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I am trying to get the File element working in pfbc, but I am not getting anything other than the filename in `$_POST['AvatarLrg']`, `$_FILES` is empty. Does anyone have a working example I can peruse?

At the top:

```
<?php
$form = new Form('trucking_edit');
$form->configure(array( "enctype" => "multipart/form-data" ));
$form->addElement(new Element_File("Profile Avatar:", "AvatarLrg"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Button);
?>
```

And in the body:

```
<?php $form->render(); ?>
```

The form displays fine and all other elements display and work correctly, just the File ones :/
Any help appreciated.

Edit: Generated HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="edit_profile" action="profile.php?pid=16&edit=save" name="tf_profileedit">
...
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="trucking_edit-element-3">Profile Avatar:</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <input type="file" name="AvatarLrg" id="trucking_edit-element-3"/>
   </div>
</div>
...
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the generated HTML of the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem; another form on the page was interfering with it (they overlapped because of old code). I removed the other form and it works. I could also remove the enctype line because PBFC automatically changes the enctype when you add a file element. Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I never used the class but cause of error is missing enctype attribute in form tag.

So check `$form->configure(array( "enctype" => "multipart/form-data" ));` line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="edit_profile" action="profile.php?pid=16&edit=save" name="tf_profileedit">
...
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="trucking_edit-element-3">Profile Avatar:</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <input type="file" name="AvatarLrg" id="trucking_edit-element-3"/>
   </div>
</div>
...
</form>
```

You forgot the enctype